# How to get operations-lift to Floor 3 - Rapid Launch Control?

Tags: the-surge

**How to get the lift (moveable operations) to the floor 3  at Nucleus area?**

I've reached the floor 2, even have uploaded the virus, but I can't move further to floor 3. This [walkthrough guide](http://thesurge.wiki.fextralife.com/Walkthrough) missing exactly this part - just like was mentioned by Sinel in the comments at 23 May 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 5-10 hours of exploration - found it. In short - drop into the hole at the outgoing train station and explore (at this point the exploration is straightforward).

In details:

1. First of all, if you haven't found the train to production B, you need to do it:

   Go out from Ops on second floor, turn right and walk around ops, downwards, after couple of turns you will see acid area and a drop to a treasure. Take this drop and drop further untill you reach a floor. Then explore the area. The area is pretty big, but exploration is straightforward and eventually you will find a new train station.
2. At the end of this train station this is a hole. Drop there. Then, go forward, kill few enemiesa and you will face a broken exo-lift, drop there as well and pick a treasure. *This is what I've found most hard to find (or rather understand that it is dropable).*
3. Now you should see two strong enemies and a power conduit. Take a small drop down to them and overload the conduit. On the other side of the room there is a stairs and a closed door, go past it, turn left and take exo-lift. There will be a panel to call the ops to floor 3.
4. You can find the ops nearby, just do a little back-tracking.

[This playthrough](https://youtu.be/Bs8glcJPTgg?t=374), shows steps 2-4.

But note, you don't need to get ops to the floor 3 to finish the game.

Comment: Just as a side note, you can overcharge the panel even if the nanite-creatures are aggro. I didn't take any damage while overcharging the panel, despite the creature swinging it's weird blades at me. After that, I just ran, screw fighting more than one of those things at a time!